# Como retirar apóstrofos de uma variável

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server

Tenho um text edit PRODUTO que vem assim: 'ADESIVO 478', com apóstrofos. Como que eu faço para que ele saia assim: ADESIVO 478 no sql server? Já tentei assim e não funciona:

```
 DECLARE @ProdutoNome VARCHAR(30);
 SET @ProdutoNome = REPLACE(''ADESIVO 478'', '''', '')
 PRINT @ProdutoNome
```

Comment: É MySQL ou SQL Server?

Comment: estou usando o sql server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Então, a forma que você fez dá certo, basta apenas você adicionar `'` no inicio e no final de `''ADESIVO 478''` por questão de sintaxe do SQL server. Ficaria assim:

```
DECLARE @ProdutoNome VARCHAR(30);
 SET @ProdutoNome = REPLACE('''ADESIVO 478''', '''', '')
 PRINT @ProdutoNome
```

[**Exemplo funcionando no SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/35181/4)

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @ProdutoNome VARCHAR(30);

SET @ProdutoNome = '''ADESIVO 478'''

 select @ProdutoNome = replace(@ProdutoNome,'''','')

 PRINT @ProdutoNome
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente adicionar o caractere de escape **\**
Ficaria assim:

```
DECLARE @ProdutoNome VARCHAR(30);
SET @ProdutoNome = REPLACE(''ADESIVO 478'', '\'', '')
PRINT @ProdutoNome
```